# Prevent calling a static method from an instance object

Tags: php

```
class Test
    {

        function __construct(){
            # code...
        }

        public static function read(){
            echo 'hello';
        }
    }

$a = new Test();

$a::read(); // it shows "hello" ??

die();
```

Is it normal that a static method can be called on instance of the class ? How I can prevent that ?

Comment: A static method is just a global function, with a limited visibility (optional).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$a::read()` is just another way of writing `Test::read();`, it calls the static method on the class, not on the instance. You don't have to worry about someone using this different way of writing it, since it does the same thing.

By the way, many languages allow that. even though it is not recommended. In Java for example you could do the following:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.test();    // Static member accessed via instance reference
        Main.test();
    }

    public static void test() { }
}
```

and it would do the same thing.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, however in my original code I have some chaining methods that return an object and I don't want that behavior because it changes all the returned value.. can I prevent that ?

Comment: Since that is an integral feature of the language, I'm pretty sure that you cannot prevent that.